# undefined control sequence error from make title command

Tags: titles, ieeeaccess

My title, authors, abstract, and keywords all look fine when I compile my document, but I keep getting the error message, "Undefined control sequence." on my `\maketitle` line. My code is:

```
%% http://www.ieee.org/
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{cite}

% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
 \usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alphabeta}


\begin{document}
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{ex-ample}


%
\title{Title example}

\author{Author~1, Author~2, Author~3,
        and~Author~4,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE}
        \thanks{Thanks example}}

\date{date example}

% The paper headers
\markboth{IEEE Access, Second mark}%
{Second mark}

% make the title area

\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}


\begin{keywords}
Keywords text
\end{keywords}


\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}
...
Document Text
...
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `\doi{<doi>}`:

[image]

```
% https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/submitting-an-article/
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Title example}

\author{%
  Author~1, Author~2, Author~3,
  and~Author~4,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE}
  \thanks{Thanks example}}

\date{date example}

\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

% The paper headers
\markboth
  {IEEE Access, Second mark}%
  {Second mark}

% make the title area
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Keywords text
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
...
Document Text
...
\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!