# How to remove the first blank page that appear in the IEEE access journal template

Tags: blank-page, research

I am about to submit a research article on IEEE access journal. I am using the overleaf version which is available online for tex editing and also I am using the IEEE access journal template. Every time when I compile my tex file, there is a blank page appear before the paper title’s page. I am trying many things but could not do it. Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This shouldn't happen. See example of IEEEacces document in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528222/undefined-control-sequence-error-from-make-title-command/528225#528225. It works fine. Please, try on its base to make own small document example, which reproduce your problem and then  present it in your question

Comment: This is the default for me too.  Even the pdf accompanying the template has the blank page.  I guess I should contact the publishing editor.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes you are right It is default as one compile the pdf the blank page appear but there is no problem on that I have contacted the editor and he said that it should be removed if the paper is published

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with `\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}`.

My problem was a small syntax mistake when listing the authors: I closed the curly bracket directly after listing all authors and before `\thanks{}`, but `\thanks{}` needs to be included inside the `\author{}` block.

For example, this is correct (from the IEEE default template):

```
\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}
\thanks{M. Shell was with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332 USA e-mail: (see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html).}
\thanks{J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised August 26, 2015.}} %<- note the closing bracket here!
```

Comment: That was precisely the same mistake I made. Thank you for being more perceptive than me.

Comment: @CGFoX Thanks for the tip: it was some days that the blank page was hanging there, right after updating authors' names ... now that I think of it

Answer (score 5):

In the IEEE Access latex template, there is a "." at the line after "\corresp" line. Remove the ".", and then the first blank page will be removed.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this for `\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}`? I also have the leading blank page there, but there's no `\corresp` in the template.